# How to get input from user, put them into a list and then choose a random one from them without having to ask multiple times

Tags: python, random

It's my 4th day learning programming so I'm very new to it. and I'm trying to get the user's info(hobbies) in one question and save them into a list then give back the user one of the hobbies they chose.
this what I've came up with

```
import random

fav_hobbies = []
hobbies = input("what are your favourite hobbies?(cooking, writing,ect) ").lower()
fav_hobbies.append(hobbies)

situation = input("so are you bored now?(answer with yes or no): ").lower()
if situation == "yes":
     print("you should try " + random.choice(fav_hobbies))

elif boredom_situation == "no":
     print("awesome! have a nice day!")
```

The problem is that instead of choosing a word among the words that user has chosen it just prints all of the things they said.

How do I fix this?

Comment: `fav_hobbies = hobbies.split(" ")` will split one string into many strings based on the separator you provide (in this case, `" "`, i.e. space. You could replace this with comma, or with more than one character).

Answer (score 0):

You are just accepting a string from the User and storing it as it is without splitting.

*Assuming that you are accepting a space separated input*, You can do this in:

```
fav_hobbies = list(input("what are your favourite hobbies?(cooking, writing,ect) ").lower().split())
```

```
import random

fav_hobbies = list(input("what are your favourite hobbies?(cooking, writing,ect) ").lower().split())

situation = input("so are you bored now?(answer with yes or no): ").lower()
if situation == "yes":
     print("you should try " + random.choice(fav_hobbies))

elif boredom_situation == "no":
     print("awesome! have a nice day!")
```

If you use some other separator like `,` you can just add it to `split(',')`